# NSView set Minimum Size on NSSplitView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

Is there a way of setting (programmatically or via interface builder) the minimum size of each of the panels (nsviews) on a NSSplitView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, check the documentation for [NSSplitViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSSplitViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#/).

Basically all you have to do is to setup a delegate for your NSSplitView and implement one or more of these three methods:

**Constraining Split Position**

```
– splitView:constrainMaxCoordinate:ofSubviewAt:
– splitView:constrainMinCoordinate:ofSubviewAt:
– splitView:constrainSplitPosition:ofSubviewAt:
```

The delegate can be set in any way you like. In interface builder, check the `delegate` outlet that you NSSplitView has, all you have to do is to connect it to the object where you adopted the NSSplitViewDelegate protocol. Programmatically, you can call `setDelegate:` on your split view and pass as argument your desired delegate.

Comment: It has a bug when you maximize the windows, but this should do fine.

Comment: @mikywan: Well, I'm not aware of that, but one thing is known to be sure: NSSplitView is bogus by itself :-) That's why I usually prefer to use alternatives, which are improved split views. One of the most popular ones is B. Walkin's BWSplitView, which is distributed as part of his BWToolkit (http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/). However, IB plugin's were lost (in a broader sense) with Xcode4. I really recommend you to take a look also on Brockerhoff's RBSplitView (http://brockerhoff.net/src/rbs.html). Very powerful.